# Issues with drupal 7 Pagination

Tags: pagination, drupal-7

I have created customized search results page in Drupal 7 and added the pagination successfully. But now the problem is when am trying to navigate the second page, the search results is not displaying the records. Please guide me ...

Comment: This question is a bit like calling a mechanic on the phone, telling him your car goes clank clank boom, and asking him to diagnose it without even seeing it.  No one can tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't even post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a search view, and I fixed this by changing the Exposed Form type to Basic instead of Input required .
I hope that this will help someone !